# PhoneGap device.uuid (VS.) iPad [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cordova, uniqueidentifier

I am looking for a way to get the device's UUID from an iPad from both PhoneGap and native Objective-C environment. The problem is that PhoneGap gives me only a hashed version of the devices UUID. For example:

```
1) device.uuid = E0AB7C8C-EFEE-4EB1-9B8F-A543575390A0
2) [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier] = 75579DE5-98C7-53B6-B2AD-7F348662CB5D
```

But as I need both values to be the same, I need one of following solutions
1) How to hash the [device uniqueIdentifier] exactly as PhoneGap does in Objective-C.
2) How to get the raw (not hashed) device's UUID from PhoneGap (JavaScript).

Does someone know how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PhoneGap is open-source, you could have looked at how it generates the UUID yourself.

Here is the method PhoneGap uses (copied from `1.7.0`). I also reproduced the Apache License just in case I should be.

```
/*
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 distributed with this work for additional information
 regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 specific language governing permissions and limitations
 under the License.
 */

- (NSString*) uniqueAppInstanceIdentifier
{
    // full path to the app folder
    NSString* bundlePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]
        stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];

    // return only the folder name (a GUID)
    return [bundlePath lastPathComponent];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`uniqueIdentifier` is deprecated as of iOS 5. You shouldn't use it at all, anymore.

Comment: ..and therefore `device.uuid` is good enough for your purposes, or, you can write your own code which hashes the device's capabilities and information and create both a JavaScript function and Objective-C function to achieve this. Or write a PhoneGap plugin which calls an Objective-C uuid method and returns the results to JavaScript.